# gae appengine + auth0 localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Goodmorning,

i have some trouble in wrinting a callback  method that it's used to login to my web app (hosted in gae)

```
@app.route('/callback')
def callback_handling():
    env = os.environ
    code = request.args.get('code')

    json_header={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

    token_url = "https://{domain}/oauth/token".format(domain='mydomain')

    token_payload = {
        'client_id': 'myid',
        'client_secret': 'mysecret',
        'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8080/callback',
        'code': code,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
    }
    encoded = urllib.urlencode(token_payload)



    user_url = "https://{domain}/userinfo?access_token={access_token}"\
            .format(access_token=token_info['access_token'])

user_info = urlfetch.Fetch(user_url, method=urlfetch.GET, headers=json_header)

    session['profile'] = user_info
    return redirect('/dashboard')
```

i costantly get error 401 unathorized..from debug console any ideas to fix?..reading over the internet i understand that i must use urlfetch from gae because is the only lib allowed in gae (requests does not in localhost)..

Comment: a piece of code is missing: token_info = urlfetch.fetch(url=token_url,
                                payload=encoded,
                                headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                                method=urlfetch.POST)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, is this : "https://{domain}/userinfo" your own endpoint or is this some third-party that you are trying to auth with?

Either way the 401 unauthorised seems legit, and being thrown by the endpoint, If "https://{domain}/userinfo" is pointing to your own endpoint then being able to see that logic would help, alternatively if it is a third-party I would recommend testing your request with something like postman, to see what your request looks like, headers etc. and make sure that it matches what the endpoint is expecting.

Hope this helps.